# How to deal with percent symbols in string when using sprintf

Tags: c, format, buffer

I have this string that I would like to add to a buffer using `sprintf`

```
https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/21611723/f7cfd480-a7ea-11ea-852c-52df94ee4644?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20220728%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220728T121916Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=fb5d8ebe7ec4f63d462d76f059a22402ec4e9931e1b9278a739dbc0c617aedbb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=21611723&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DQuasar.v1.4.0.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
```

like so i am using

```
    FILE *p;
    char url[] = "https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/21611723/f7cfd480-a7ea-11ea-852c-52df94ee4644?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20220728%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220728T121916Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=fb5d8ebe7ec4f63d462d76f059a22402ec4e9931e1b9278a739dbc0c617aedbb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=21611723&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DQuasar.v1.4.0.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream";
    sprintf(request, "%s %s %s", "GET", url, "HTTP/1.1"); 
    p = fopen("out.txt" , "w");
    fprintf(p , request);
    fclose(p);
```

this results in a malformed string  from `out.txt`

```
GET https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/21611723/f7cfd480-a7ea-11ea-852c-52df94ee4644?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A0.000000202207280.000000us-east-10.000000s30.000000aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220728T121916Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=fb5d8ebe7ec4f63d462d76f059a22402ec4e9931e1b9278a739dbc0c617aedbb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=21611723&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B            0.000000ilename%3DQuasar.v1.4.0.zip&response-content-type=application0.000000octet-stream HTTP/1.1
```

In `out.txt` there is a space gap `%3B%20filename` -> `%3B            0.000000ilename`

what workaround do I have to copy the url to the buffer, is there a way to escape strings like `%20f` with out looping over them and decoding from url to ascii again

I outputting the request buffer to a text file just to inspect the output because the terminal does not show the problem properly

Comment: If the `request` is fully formed, and you don't need `printf` to replace anything, you should be able to use `fputs` instead.

Comment: If none of the answers helped you to resolve this issue, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @TedLyngmo it does not get any minimal reproducible example more than this you have the string that causes the problem and the function which is not performing as expected what else do i have to add?

Comment: @sinister it's not reproducible. We can't compile your code and see the issue.

Comment: For example: We can't see how you defined `request`. Have you checked if it's big enough like I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is very simple:

```
fprintf(p , "%s", request);
```

Basically, never use the string you want to output as a format. Use proper format to display string

Comment: I am using `FILE` to view the resulting request string i am not planing on writing the request buffer to a text file

Comment: @sinister how does it matter? does it change something?

Comment: it does matter, the problem is related to `sprintf` not properly formatting the string and `%3B%20filename` is outputted as `%3B            0.000000ilename`

Comment: @sinister you need to understand that "format" parameter is to pass the string you want to output, only the *format* string. It is not related to sprint at all. You simply do not know how `printf` works.

Answer (score 4):

Since `request` is the result that you want to send, don't use it as a formatting string. Use the function designed to send strings as they are, `fputs`:

```
fputs(request, p);
```

If that doesn't resolve all issues, I suspect that `request` is not large enough to hold the string you `sprintf` into it. Use `snprintf` to confirm. If `request` is an automatic variable, just compare with `sizeof request`:

```c
int len = snprintf(request, sizeof request, "%s %s %s", "GET", url, "HTTP/1.1");
if((unsigned) len >= sizeof request || len < 0) {
    printf("%d >= %zu or < 0\n", len, sizeof request);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: the problem is not about outputting the buffer to a file you can remove the part which outputs the buffer to a file and use `printf` instead the error will still be there

Comment: @sinister I added a possible cause for that

Comment: How can `len >= sizeof request` be true? AFAIK `snprintf` can  never fill more tan `sizeof(request) - 1` characters.

Comment: @DavidRanieri It will never _fill_ more but it'll return what it _would have_ filled, had there been enough space, so if it returns `sizeof request` or more, the buffer was too small.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I see what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to escaping the `%` character, you should create a function with a loop that goes over the characters of the buffer and checks if any of them is `%` in this case it should add `%` then add the original `%` to escape that character then continue until you finish all the buffer

```
void esc(char * old, char * new)
{
    int old_size = strlen(old), i=0,j=0;
    while ( i < old_size)
    {
        if (old[i] == '%')
        {
            new[j] = '%';
            j++;
            new[j] = old[i];    
        }
        new[j] = old[i];
        i++,j++;
    }
    new[j] = '\0';
}


int main()
{
    char new[1024]; 
    char buffer[4096];
    char link[] = "https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/21611723/f7cfd480-a7ea-11ea-852c-52df94ee4644?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20220728%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220728T132853Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=8de49cce44acb53aff3a2d284cd402f4b1a7cd6fa9335ec7c8be5b3a5d96d24c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=21611723&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DQuasar.v1.4.0.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream";
    esc(link , new);
    sprintf(buffer , "%s %s HTTP/1.1", "GET", new);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

final result looks like this

```
GET https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/21611723/f7cfd480-a7ea-11ea-852c-52df94ee4644?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%%2F20220728%%2Fus-east-1%%2Fs3%%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220728T132853Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=8de49cce44acb53aff3a2d284cd402f4b1a7cd6fa9335ec7c8be5b3a5d96d24c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=21611723&response-content-disposition=attachment%%3B%%20filename%%3DQuasar.v1.4.0.zip&response-content-type=application%%2Foctet-stream HTTP/1.1
```